# Is it possible to push or pull a private github to a remote server without that server having rsa credentials or even a github account

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to push or pull a private `github` to a remote server without that server having rsa credentials or worse it's own github account.

ive tried `ssh-keygen` a new key on the server and adding it to my personal github profile. that doesnt seem to work. Any pointers here.

The next step: make a github account for my machine, add it to the private project and then git with that machine account.

and if thats the best option; then github will fill up with machine accounts.

Comment: so you can't do a git init there?  You could use scp/rsync...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking sounds like ssh forwarding. Ssh forwarding is for execute commands that require your local keys in a remote server (For an extended explanation about ssh forwarding, go here: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd). Github has a guide for it: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding.

To sum up the content of the guide, you should have be able to connect from your local machine to Github. You can test it with:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
# Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide
# shell access.
```

Once you have access to github, you have to have a file in your local machine in `~/.ssh/config` with:

```
Host example.com
ForwardAgent yes
```

replacing `example.com` with the hostname of your server.

Then you can connect to the server and run again `ssh -T git@github.com`, just to know if ssh forwarding is working.